# splashr - Web scraping: Finding precise mouse coords for splash_click() in Splashr

Tags: r

I'm working with the splashr package (for dynamic web scraping), a useful alternative to selenium which doesn't seem to be updated right now. I'm following the tutorial here.

https://github.com/hrbrmstr/splashr

I'm specifically interested in splashr's `splash_click()` function. As I work through the example at the bottom of the page, it doesn't seem to work properly for me.

```
splash_local %>%
splash_plugins(TRUE) %>%
splash_go("https://gis.cdc.gov/GRASP/Fluview/FluHospRates.html") %>%
splash_wait(4) %>%
splash_click(460, 550) %>%
splash_wait(2) %>%
splash_click(230, 85) %>%
splash_wait(2) %>%
splash_png()
```

The png that returns to me is covered up by the pop-up that initially appears when you visit that site. In other words, `splash_click()` did not seem to work for me. Reading the documentation, I noticed that the coords in the `splash_click()` function need to be "relative to viewport". I'm not sure what that means, but I'm guessing mine aren't.

How can I be sure I am using the right coords?

Answer (score 0):

after splash_wait(4), try inserting   splash_send_keys(") %>% 
to dismiss the popup.